# FluentUI FluentDialogProvider fails to initialise in Blazor Server on .NET 8

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-8.0, fluent-ui

I'm trying to get a custom dialog working using FluentUI in Blazor Server .NET 8.
(https://www.fluentui-blazor.net/Dialog)

I have added `<FluentDialogProvider />` to the bottom of my layout and registered the service in `Program.cs`

```
builder.Services.AddFluentUIComponents();
```

When I access the page I get an error stating that there is no registered service of type `Microsoft.FluentUI.AspNetCore.Components.DialogService`. Reading the docs, `builder.Services.AddFluentUIComponents();` should register the dialog service in the DI container. Seems not to be here.

If I add `builder.Services.AddScoped<DialogService>();` the page loads but when I call `OpenDialogAsync` on my component I get a new error stating that `<FluentDialogProvider />` hasn't been placed in my main layout when in fact it has.

I feel like I'm following the docs correctly but the errors seem to conflict with the docs. I just cannot get it to work.

`Program.cs`:

```
builder.Services.AddFluentUIComponents();
```

`MainLayout.razor`:

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<FluentLayout>
    <FluentHeader Height="65" Style="background-color: #012389;">
        <HeaderText />
    </FluentHeader>
    <FluentStack Class="main" Orientation="Orientation.Horizontal" Width="100%">
        <NavMenu />
        <FluentBodyContent>
            <div class="content">
                @Body
            </div>
        </FluentBodyContent>
    </FluentStack>

    <FluentToastProvider Position="ToastPosition.BottomRight" RemoveToastsOnNavigation="false" ShowCloseButton="true" />
    <FluentDialogProvider />

</FluentLayout>
```

`MyPage.razor`:

```
private async Task OpenDialogAsync(int Id)
{
    if (materials is not null)
    {
        Material? material = await MaterialService.GetMaterialByIdAsync(Id);

        if (material is not null)
        {
            var dialog = await DialogService.ShowDialogAsync<MaterialDialog>(material, new DialogParameters()
                {
                    Title = "Edit Material",
                    PreventDismissOnOverlayClick = true,
                    PreventScroll = true
                });

            var result = await dialog.Result;

            if (!result.Cancelled && result.Data is not null)
            {
                // Do something to save the record
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of FluentUI are you using.  You should see `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.FluentUI.AspNetCore.Components" Version="4.*-* " />`   And I asumme you're injecting IDialogService - `@inject IDialogService DialogService` in MyPage.

Comment: I'm using `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.FluentUI.AspNetCore.Components" Version="4.2.1" />` and yes I'm using `@inject DialogService DialogService` in `MyPage.razor`.

Comment: OK, I can't see your problem.  Here's my test demo for you to look at: https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/SO77728510

Comment: Bit of a face palm this one Shaun but your github example helped me find it. I was injecting `DialogService` into my page rather than `IDialogService`. So annoying lol. Thank you.

Comment: NP. The bit of code you didn't show!